# The POST method is not supported for route admin/bill. Supported methods: GET, HEAD

Tags: ajax, laravel, post, get, head

In Laravel i use ajax for adding and fetching data from MySQL Database through blade template, i have add form summation on onsubmit event. Please Help me.

My codes are.
Route.php

```
Route::get('admin/bill',[BillingController::class, 'bill'])->name('billing');
    
Route::post('admin/billing/add',[BillingController::class, 'billadd'])->name('admin.bill.add');
```

Controller.php

```
public function billadd(Request $request){

        $request->validate([
            'customer_name'=>'required',
            'mobile_number'=>'required',
            'current_date'=>'required',
            'current_time'=>'required',
            'bill_number'=>'required',
            'product_name'=>'required',
            'batch_number'=>'required',
            'variant'=>'required',
            'price'=>'required',
            'quantity'=>'required',
            'tax_percent'=>'required',            
        ]);

        $posBill = new PosBilling();

        $posBill->customer_name=$request->customer_name;
        $posBill->customer_phone=$request->mobile_number;
        $posBill->billing_date=$request->current_date;
        $posBill->billing_time=$request->current_time;
        $posBill->bill_number=$request->bill_number;
        $posBill->product_name=$request->product_name;
        $posBill->batch_number=$request->batch_number;
        $posBill->variant = $request->variant;

        $unitPrice = $posBill->price = $request->price;  // One product price
        
        $totalQuantity = $posBill->quantity = $request->quantity;  // Total quantity of product
        
        $totalAmount = $posBill->quantity_value = $unitPrice * $totalQuantity;  // Total amount of product
        

        // Discount Calculation

        $discountPercent = $posBill->discount_percent = $request->discount_percent;  // Discount percent
        
        $discountPrice= $posBill->discount_amt = ($totalAmount) * ($discountPercent / 100);   // Discount amount
       
        $amountWithDiscount= $posBill->amount_with_discount = $totalAmount - $discountPrice;  // with Discount amount of products
        
        // Tax Calculation

        $taxPercent= $posBill->tax_percent = $request->tax_percent;  // Tax percent of product
        
        $TaxPrice = $posBill->tax_amount = ($amountWithDiscount) * ($taxPercent / 100); // Amount of products tax
        
        $CGST = $TaxPrice / 2;  // CGST amount of products
        
        $SGST = $TaxPrice / 2;  // SGST amount of products
        
        $amountWithTax = $posBill->net_amount = $TaxPrice + $amountWithDiscount;  // with Tax amount of products

        $i= 1;

        if($i == 1){            
            $posBill->save();
            $i++;

            // echo $i;
        }
        
        if($i>1){

            $billNumber = $request->bill_number;

            $billingProduct = PosBilling::where('bill_number', $billNumber)->get();

            
        }           
        return response()->json(['billingProduct'=>$billingProduct]);
        
    }
```

blade.php

```
 <form  method="post"  id="addProduct">
    @csrf
<div class="row">
                            <div class="col-2">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="">Product Name <b>*</b></label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="product_name" id="product_name"
                                        placeholder="Product Name">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-2">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="">Batch Number <b>*</b></label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="batch_number" id="batch_number">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-1">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="">Variant <b>*</b></label>
                                    <select class="form-control" name="variant" id="variant">
                                        <option value="" selected disabled>Variant</option>
                                        @foreach ($variant as $item)
                                            <option value="{{ $item->id }}">{{ $item->unit_name }}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-1">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="">Price <b>*</b></label>
                                    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="price" id="price">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-1">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="">Quantity <b>*</b></label>
                                    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="quantity" id="quantity">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-2">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="">Tax <b>*</b></label>
                                    <select class="form-control" name="tax_percent" id="tax_percent">
                                        <option value="" selected disabled>Tax</option>
                                        <option value="0">0% GST</option>
                                        <option value="5">5% GST</option>
                                        <option value="12">12% GST</option>
                                        <option value="18">18% GST</option>
                                        <option value="28">28% GST</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-2">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="">Discount[%]</label>
                                    <input type="discount" class="form-control" name="discount_percent" id="discount_percent"
                                        placeholder="Ex- 5, 10, 30, etc">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="col-1">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    {{-- <button><a href="#" class="btn btn-success" id="add">Add</a></button> --}}
                                    <button class="btn btn-success" id="add" >Add</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

blade.php (ajax code)

```
<script>
                        jQuery('#add').onsubmit(function(e){
                            e.preventDefault();
                            alert("Test");
                            break;
                            var formData = jQuery(this).serialize();
                            $.ajax({
                                url: "{{ route('admin.bill.add') }}",
                                type: "post",
                                data: formData,
                                success: function(response){                                    
                                    console.log(response);

 }
                            });
                        });
                    </script>
```

I'm trying to submit data without page loading and fetch data both using one controller function.

Comment: What error you are getting. in your jquery you are calling onsubmit on button id. var formData = jQuery(this).serialize(); is not for form it is for button try this in your jquery code  var formData = jQuery('#addProduct').serialize();

Answer (score 0):

In the form tag please add the action in the following manner

```
<form  method="post" action="javascript:void(0)"  id="addProduct">
```

and one more thing
Please modify the line `jQuery(this).serialize()` to `jQuery('#addProduct').serialize`. as we are not getting the value from the button.
if it will not work then add a button `type="submit"`.

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery is quite broken, which results in the form being posted to the page you're are on already; and due to your current route settings, you get the error that the route doesn't support POST.

You should be able to get the JavaScript working by using the `on()` function instead and targeting the right form element:

```
jQuery('#add').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = jQuery('#addProduct').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: "{{ route('admin.bill.add') }}",
        type: "post",
        data: formData,
        success: function(response){                                    
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
```